# I have an HTML5 canvas, I want to make an animated GIF of that canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, converters, animated-gif

I have a simple HTML5 page, with a single canvas, upon which a scientific visualization is drawn.

I would like to take X frames of that canvas (probably by using `toDataURL()` at key points), and turn that into an animated GIF that I can download.

Alternatively a nice way to save images from the DOM to disc without prompting, or to zip 100-200 images for saving with prompting that can be GIFed elsewhere.

Is there any ready solution to this problem? And I don't mean recording an AVI of part of the DOM, saving it, extracting frames, and rebaking it into a GIF.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no native functionality to save out animated GIFs but, there is this library written in JavaScript which can do it for you:
https://github.com/antimatter15/jsgif

Saving images to local disk without prompting is not possible. You will have either:

- Create a link the user can click on to save (and chose location). Most up-to-date browsers will allow you to use the download attribute for the anchor tag (<a>).
- Send it to server and then back with download attributes in header to prompt user for location

**Update**

If you want to just use the browser as a useful host for local tasks you can always disable these restrictions. Here for Chrome:

To disable all security measures start Chrome from command line with this flag:

```
chrome.exe --disable-web-security
```

If you only want to use local files (file:// is in any case necessary):

```
chrome.exe --allow-file-access-from-files
```

I am not 100% sure of if these allow you to *save* to local disk but they are as close as you get without modifying the code base of the browser yourself.

Hope this helps!

Comment: +1. Kevin Kwoks (antimatters) `jsgif` is a nice library for making canvas sequences into a gif.  And agreed, saving images to local disk violates security concerns (and is just plain rude!).

Comment: @AdrianSeeley if you want to use this with you local env. only you can start the browser, here Chrome, with a flag overiding the restriction for using local files (file:// is needed regardless). Start Chrome from command line like this: `chrome.exe --disable-web-security` or `chrome.exe --allow-file-access-from-files`. (updated answer with these)